# deploy war in Tomcat

Tags: java, solr, tomcat5.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deploy war in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988196/deploy-war-in-tomcat)

I Deployed solr.war in tomcat webapps folder and extracted it. while running it in on browser i am gettong the following exception. please suggest me what i need to do for it.

> SEVERE: Could not start SOLR. Check
>   solr/home property
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find
>   resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath
>   or 'solr/conf/', cwd=C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 5.5     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3635)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what the error says: place `solrconfig.xml`in your classpath (`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\classes`) or in the `solr/conf/` folder.

Comment: es: yes, it is saying to place solrconfig.xml to place in classpath. But problem is i m not getting about which class path it is talking about

Comment: I follow the link wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Single_Solr_app and did what is it saying. but still getting the same exception. i might b doning wrong in setting SOLR_HOME. I set it as environment variable SOLR_HOME=C:\Solr\solr\conf and also configure in tomcat as -Dsolr.solr.home=c:\Solr

Answer (score 2):

a) The reason being you haven't set the SOLR_HOME property. When you define the $SOLR_HOME it looks for a SOLR_HOME/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml which defines the data directory for solr. This data directory is nothing but a place where Solr stores index.
b) Also, you need to add the SolrContext.xml file in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost which specifies the location of war and the solr home. It automatically picks up the solr.war from this position and copies it to webapps folder.

Follow this link for detail instruction. 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Simple_Example_Install

Comment: I follow the link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Single_Solr_app  and did what is it saying. but still getting the same exception. i might b doning wrong in setting SOLR_HOME. I set it as environment variable SOLR_HOME=C:\Solr\solr\conf and also configure in tomcat as -Dsolr.solr.home=c:\Solr

Comment: Pål Brattberg,Matt: Thanks all. Now i am not getting any exception. its running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Watch that the solr war doesn't have a preconfigured "solr/home" with preconfigured cores inside the .war, you have to make the solr.xml (I use Jetty, so it's the solr.xml in the context's directory) point to a valid solr/home with a configured core.

I would suggest you start by looking at the solr examples that come with the binaries.  Personally i made strides once i had a solr environment set up in eclipse http://www.lucidimagination.com/developers/articles/setting-up-apache-solr-in-eclipse.

Comment: I follow the link wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Single_Solr_app and did what is it saying. but still getting the same exception. i might b doning wrong in setting SOLR_HOME. I set it as environment variable SOLR_HOME=C:\Solr\solr\conf and also configure in tomcat as -Dsolr.solr.home=c:\Solr